# Dynamic keys in JSON document using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, ecmascript-6

This question is specific to Node.js ES6.

I'm trying to create a JSON document to insert into DB (Mongo) the keys for inserting document would be values from input. Example

My input looks like this

```
[
   "key1":"val1",
   "key2":"val2",
   "key3":"val3",
   "key4":"val4"
]
```

My document that will be generated based on the values sent, so the document being inserted should look like

```
{
    "val1":"someOtherVal1",
    "val2":"someOtherVal2",
    "val3":"someOtherVal3",
    "val4":"someOtherVal4"
}
```

Comment: What is this input? Text? It's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const input = {var1: "v1", var2: "v2"};

const mongoObj = {
    [input.var1]: "someOtherVal1",
    [input.var2]: "someOtherVal2"
  };
  
console.log(mongoObj);
```

You want to use computed property put your variable between brackets:

```
  {
      [variable] : "value"
  }
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but can you please help me how to achieve this, I tried using `${key}` but that dint work.